# Can I retrieve all sales information for in app purchase of iOS app?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect

I've built an ios application using Flutter, and I've made some sales. I'd like to retrieve all sales information (so the list of users who has purchased the in-app purchase) and I can't figure out how to do this.

At first, I tried to look on the app store connect page, but I couldn't find it. Then I found out the SDK offers something similar, but to use the api, I need a `transaction id`, which I don't know where to get.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, and happy new year!

Comment: You cannot get the purchaser's identity from the App Store. The transaction id is provided to your app when the purchase is made. If you have user accounts in your app and map the transaction id against the user account then you have some identity for the purchaser, otherwise it is anonymous.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your reply. Okay, it makes sense, it's also a privacy concern. Yeah, that's exactly what I want to do - to map the transaction id with their user accounts. Unfortunately I didn't keep track of them when the purchase was made, does this mean there is no way for me to map them any more?

Comment: You could release an update to your app that retrieves user's purchase history and sends it to your server

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi paul, thank you again for your reply. I've been googling for days and you are my only hope! Okay, that is a great solution to my problem. Thank you again so much, really appreciate your help!!!!!!!!